# Best way to manage preferences from dev to live server

Tags: database, synchronization

If I have a development server, with an app that holds its preferences in a database table. And the database is synced over to the live server, any preference with path information would render the live server to have wrong path values.

How does one best handle a situation like this?
Thanks
Rich

Comment: Need more information like how is the database synced?  Either way, the best answer is to simply not copy the table with those settings from dev to live...

Comment: Some test or garbage data usually is created in test DB during development. How can you synchronize live db with test db then??

Comment: Currently I just dump, then import the data. I suppose I could just pick and choose the tables, but I didn't know how others handle something like this. For example maintaining Wordpress installs.